# Building URL using URI builder

Tags: java, android, url, uribuilder

Encoded URL -

```
https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?tqx=out:JSON&tq=select%20*%20where%20((A%20%3D%20201))&key=1424bS7kU8nJbHdu4QdoAFdIdWDSnmEnj2NqfMb6rPTU
```

Decoded URL -

```
https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?tqx=out:JSON&tq=select * where ((A= 201))&key=1424bS7kU8nJbHdu4QdoAFdIdWDSnmEnj2NqfMb6rPTU
```

In the URI builder which URL we should use encoded or decoded?

Also the given code is not working :-

```
String xyz="1424bS7kU8nJbHdu4QdoAFdIdWDSnmEnj2NqfMb6rPTU";
    String X="201";


    final String STUDENT_RECORD_URL="https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?tqx=out:JSON&tq=select*where";
    final String Frag1 = "A";
    final String Frag2 =  "key";
    Builder builder = Uri.parse(STUDENT_RECORD_URL).buildUpon();
    builder.appendQueryParameter(Frag1,X);
    builder.appendQueryParameter(Frag2,xyz);
    String finalUri=builder.build().toString();
```

Comment: Hmmm. This isn't JavaScript...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding what your query params are. They should each be key-value pairs in your url. For your url `https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?tqx=out:JSON&tq=select * where ((A= 201))&key=1424bS7kU8nJbHdu4QdoAFdIdWDSnmEnj2NqfMb6rPTU`, building it would look something like:

```
final String STUDENT_RECORD_URL="https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq";

Builder builder = Uri.parse(STUDENT_RECORD_URL).buildUpon();
builder.appendQueryParameter("txq", "out:JSON");
builder.appendQueryParameter("tq", "select * where ((A= 201))");
builder.appendQueryParameter("key", "1424bS7kU8nJbHdu4QdoAFdIdWDSnmEnj2NqfMb6rPTU");

String finalUri = builder.build().toString();
```

The `appendQueryParameter` method will automatically url encode your parameters.

Comment: how to get 201 entered dynamically by user?

Comment: But its not working   String X='201';

        final String STUDENT_RECORD_URL="https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq";

        Builder builder = Uri.parse(STUDENT_RECORD_URL).buildUpon();
        builder.appendQueryParameter("txq", "out:JSON");
        builder.appendQueryParameter("tq", "select * where ((A= X))");
        builder.appendQueryParameter("key", "1424bS7kU8nJbHdu4QdoAFdIdWDSnmEnj2NqfMb6rPTU");

Comment: You're using the String "X" instead of your variable here: "select * where ((A= X))". You need to close the quotes before referencing your variable, like this: "select * where ((A= " + X + "))".

Comment: if some one entered the wrong variable that is not available in the JSON then how to identify that?

Comment: You should be validating the input or error handling the response.

Comment: You may want to do some independent research first, then ask that in a new question.